# DataGrid gets Index -1 does not have a value when selected row changes

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple datagrid, that displays contents of some List variable. I have two buttons related to it, one for adding contents to the List variable and refreshing the datagrid, the other for removing it and refreshing also.

I can add the objects without problems, however, if I change the selected row, I get an error saying "Index -1 does not have a value." No idea why.

The code for setting up the datagrid is as follows:

```
allTravellersDataGrid.DataSource = allTravellers;
```

where allTravellers is the List I was talking about above.

The button for adding the content to allTravellers List is as follows:

```
private void addAttendee_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (attendeeName.Text == "" || attendeeSurname.Text == "" || attendeeBirthDate.Text == "" || attendeeIdNumber.Text == "")
        { MessageBox.Show("Not all information regarding the attendee entered"); }
        else
        {
            allTravellers.Add(dt.prepareTraveller(attendeeName.Text, attendeeSurname.Text, attendeeBirthDate.Text, attendeeIdNumber.Text));
            allTravellersDataGrid.DataSource = null;
            allTravellersDataGrid.DataSource = allTravellers;
            allTravellersDataGrid.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

and at last the code for button for removal of objects from the list looks like this:

```
private void removeAttendee_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        traveller travellerToRemove = (traveller)allTravellersDataGrid.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
        allTravellers.Remove(travellerToRemove);
        allTravellersDataGrid.Refresh();
    }
```

Is there anybody here who's not helpless like me in finding out what is causing the index problem?

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Index+-1+does+not+have+a+value+C%23#pq=index+-1+does+not+have+a+value+c%23&hl=en&sugexp=pfwl&tok=vGTaR7u2DyGSuxPKL_bFXA&cp=32&gs_id=k&xhr=t&q=%22Index+-1+does+not+have+a+value%22+C%23&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=%22Index+-1+does+not+have+a+value%22+C%23&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=76147c48b2eb760f&biw=1920&bih=943

Comment: Do you have an Event for the Index Change on the Grid? If so, post the code.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that when you get this error, you are not currently on a selected item.  (List controls that don't have an item selected indicate that with a '-1').  Checking for a valid item before you try to remove it will probably solve your problem.

I also used a BindingList, not sure what difference it will make for you.

assume a form with a 
textbox named attendeeName
add button named addBtn
remove button named removeBtn
grid named allTravellersDataGrid

This works:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using StackOverFlowWinForms.Model;

namespace StackOverFlowWinForms
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private BindingList<Traveller> _allTravellers = new BindingList<Traveller>();
    public BindingList<Traveller> allTravellers { get { return _allTravellers; } }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        allTravellers.Add(new Traveller("Fred"));
        allTravellers.Add(new Traveller("George"));
        allTravellers.Add(new Traveller("Sam"));
        allTravellers.Add(new Traveller("Mary"));

        this.allTravellersDataGrid.DataSource = allTravellers;

    }

    private void addBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (attendeeName.Text == "")
        { MessageBox.Show("Not all information regarding the attendee entered"); }
        else
        {
            allTravellers.Add(new Traveller(attendeeName.Text));
        }

    }

    private void removeBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (allTravellersDataGrid.CurrentRow != null) 
        {
            Traveller travellerToRemove = (Traveller)allTravellersDataGrid.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
            allTravellers.Remove(travellerToRemove);

        }

    }
}
}

using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace StackOverFlowWinForms.Model
{
public class Traveller 

{

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    #endregion 

    private string _attendeeName;
    public string attendeeName 
    { 
        get 
        {
            return _attendeeName; 
        } 
        set 
        {
            _attendeeName = value; 
            NotifyPropertyChanged("attendeeName"); 
        } 
    }


    public Traveller()
    {
        this.attendeeName = "Unknown";
    }
    public Traveller(string name)
    {
        this.attendeeName = name;
    }
}
}
```